# How does GLib/GObject Reference Counting garbage collection system prevent race conditions in heavy-multithreaded code?

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, glibc, reference-counting, gobject

I've read [this great answer from @jon-harrop in Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/How-do-reference-counting-and-garbage-collection-compare/answer/Jon-Harrop-1?srid=O7So&share=1) to the question **How do reference counting and garbage collection compare?** and there, it is said that one of the disadvantages of reference counting is *that multithreaded reference counting is non-deterministic because increments and decrements race*.

Then he goes on explaining how most of those disadvantages are solved or worked-around by some systems, giving particular examples; except in the case of this disadvantage.

So I'm wondering: does GLib/GObject's reference counting have any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It uses the [Atomic Operations](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Atomic-Operations.html) support int GLib.  On processors/compilers which support atomic operations it uses that (i.e., [Atomic Builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) for GCC, [InterlockedCompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttk2z1ws%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on Windows, etc.), and it falls back on a mutex.